# Writing to a table in a text file issue

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I previously made a database of products. 
Its headings appeared as shown below.

`Product    | Code Product | Product Price |  Current Stock | Threshold Level |`

One of the products I have is a Pepsi can, which is shown below.

`Pepsi      |  30994663    |     0.50      |      30        |     5           |`

The entire text file looks exactly like this -
 
`Product    | Code Product | Product Price |  Current Stock | Threshold Level |` 
`Pepsi      |  30994663    |     0.50      |      30        |     5           |`

`iPhone     |  12345670    |     5.00      |      34        |     8           |`

I want to change the value of current stock after a user has purchased 1 *Pepsi* can.

My code appears as such so far:

```
stockID = 30994663
stockNew = 29

with open('SODatabaseProduct.txt','r+') as stockDatabase:
    for line in stockDatabase:
        if str(stockID)in line:

            product=line.strip().split('|')
            product[3] = str('stockNew')
```

This changes the third value 'current stock' to 29 *in the dictionary*. 
I want to transfer the change to the textfile using `file.write.`

I tried this method.

```
stockDatabase.write("<Br>" + str(product))
```

This, however write the dictionary in code form to the text file.

I want the following result.

`Product    | Code Product | Product Price |  Current Stock | Threshold Level |` 
`Pepsi      |  30994663    |     0.50      |      29        |     5           |`

`iPhone     |  12345670    |     5.00      |      34        |     8           |`

Of course, the line I will need  to edit will need to be the one with the correct Code Product, but I can't seem to find a method that fits what I need. Can someone help?

Comment: Does the txt file has to look like this, or would it be okay to use JSON format?

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog yeah the text file needs to look like that!

Comment: Even though a text file is a sequence, like a list, it's not stored in the computers memory (RAM). Instead it's typically stored on a physical device like a harddisk. While updating a text file in-place _can be done_, doing so is usually difficult and inefficient, chiefly because each line (or record) in it is potentially a different length and could start anywhere. For these reasons, other approaches are usually employed, like reading the entire file into memory, updating it, and then rewriting the entire thing.

Comment: @martineau I am getting rid of this question and considering a new approach to the program! Thanks for your suggestion! I am doing what you have suggested. My apologies.